# facing cache issue in activecollab routers

Tags: php, open-source, content-management-system, project, activecollab

I am developing activecollab custom module; facing an issue related to Routers.

I by mistake type wrong action name in Router's action where we need to define in router, but after getting error I updated that action name but activecollabs still reading a previous action i removed files from **cache** and **complie** folders but reading previous action.

please share if you ever face this problem in development of activecollab module..

By mistake I did this: (action=>'views')

```
Router::map('mymodule_view', 'mymodule/view/:request_id', array('controller' => 'mymodule', 'action' => 'views' ), array('req_id' => Router::MATCH_ID) );
```

but after getting error i update above code by this:  (action=>'views')

```
Router::map('mymodule_view', 'mymodule/view/:request_id', array('controller' => 'mymodule', 'action' => 'view' ), array('req_id' => Router::MATCH_ID) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that your system is in development mode. Open `config/config.php` and confirm that APPLICATION_MODE is set to `in_development`:

```
define('APPLICATION_MODE', 'in_development');
```

Now that you have that covered, go to activeCollab and you'll have Developer toolbar available in the lower right corner of the application interface, next to activeCollab powered button (it has a red bug icon). Use this tool to clear cache, rebuild images etc.

PS: You can also clear all files from `/cache` folder, just in case.

Comment: its really great indeed; before this I really dont know about the right bottom DEVELOPER button, now its working for me, many thanks